# When debugging the call stack inside __init__ why is there no trace of calls to __new__?

Tags: python

I am digging into how python actually instantiates class instances and initializes them, I know **new** is invoked before **init** and should return an instance of the matching class in order for **init** to be automatically called, however why is there no trace of **new** in the stack trace at this point?

```
class ArmyTank:
    def __init__(self):
        import traceback
        for line in traceback.format_stack():
            print(line.strip())


ArmyTank()
```

Stack to stdout:

```
File "C:/workspace/learning-python/dunder_methods/dunder_init.py", line 52, in <module>
    ArmyTank()
File "C:/workspace/learning-python/dunder_methods/dunder_init.py", line 48, in __init__
    for line in traceback.format_stack():

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `__init__` doesn't call `__new__`. `__init__` is called after `__new__` has already been executed. The stack trace only contains method-calls that were called while executing the current method

Comment: doesnt __new__ call __init__ thus the stack should indicate that? perhaps using traceback.format_stack() is not quite what I am looking for to view the full stack?  I would expected my printed stack to include calls to __new__ prior to calling __init__ ?

Comment: @symon No. `type.__call__` calls `__new__`, then if the return value is an instance of the class originally passed to `__new__`, then `type.__call__` calls `__init__`.

Comment: oh wow thanks,  how come there is nothing regarding type.__call__ in the stack trace at this point? shouldn't there be some lines for it invoking `__init__` and `__new__` prior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__new__` and `__init__` are both called by `type.__call__` (or whatever metaclass is relevant instead of `type`). You can think of `type.__call__` as being defined as

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(obj, cls):
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

`ArmyTank` is equivalent to `type.__call__(ArmyTank)`.

So, by the time your `__init__` method is called, the call to `__new__` has already been made and completed, and no longer appears in the current call stack.

The call to `type.__call__` is probably left out of the stack trace as a simplification; it's mostly an implementation detail that wouldn't be of use while debugging Python-level code.

Comment: Is their a book/encyclopedia which holds this and more knowledge like this ?